# Trying to sequentially divide each number in a list in python, how though?

Tags: python, division

'''

```
numlist = [ 81, 9, 3]
#List methods
for num in numlist:
    numlist[numlist.index(num)] = int(num)
#list comprehension
 numlist = [int(num) for num in numlist]

i=0

for i in numlist:
    a = i
    b = i + 1
    quotient = a / b
print(numlist[-1])
```

'''

What I am trying to do is get 81 / 9 and then the quotient is divided by 3. the whole operation gives me 3, which my intention is to get the result of 1.

Any advice would be great.

The intention of this basic question is to divide the dividend by the divisor to give me a quotient. Then the quotient is divided by the next divisor and the quotient ends up as the dividend.

I have tried:

```
numlist = input("Enter space-separated numbers (2 min) ").split()
#List methods
for num in numlist:
    numlist[numlist.index(num)] = int(num)
#list comprehension
numlist = [int(num) for num in numlist]

from functools import reduce
reduce(lambda x,y:x/y, numlist)
print(numlist[-1])
```

but the result is 3

Comment: You said that you want to do 81/9 and then the quotient is divided by 3. 81/9 is 9, and 9/3 is 3. Why do you expect this operation to return 1 as a result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`numlist = [int(num) for num in numlist]` should be replaced with `numlist = list(map(int,numlist))` because you should never mess with an iterable you are iterating over.

Secondly, your last for loop for doing the division is wrong. Instead try this.

```
nextNum = numlist[1]
for i in range(len(newList)-1):
    nextNum = newList[i] / nextNum
```

all together.

```
numlist = [ 81, 9, 3]
newList = [int(num) for num in numlist]
nextNum = numlist[1]
for i in range(len(newList)-1):
    nextNum = newList[i] / nextNum
print(nextNum)
```

out

```
1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sequentially divide integers contained in an iterable in Python, functools.reduce can do this very efficiently:

```python
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> reduce(lambda x,y: x/y, [81,9,3])
3.0
>>>
```

The reduce function takes a function and iterable as arguments. It feeds (in this case) 81 and 9 from the iterable as the x,y inputs to the lambda function. It then takes the result of that operation, and the next value in the iterable (a 3 in this case) and feeds *those* to the x,y inputs to the lambda function. The result is the same as doing (81 / 9) / 3

Answer (score 0):

Check your math. The correct answer is 3 only. Also, whatever code you have posted is not even trying to perform sequential division, you just end up returning the last element of your list, which ended up being 3 in this case.
A simple way to accomplish the sequential division would be:

```
numlist = [ 81, 9, 3]

res = numlist[0]
for num in numlist[1:]:
    res = res/num

print(res)
```

Out:

```
3.0
```